# Put text and button in paraller

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im using the following code and currently the text and the button is in different side of the
screen,the text is above the button ,I want the both of them be in **parallel**
how should I do that?

```
<h4>my text</h4>
<div class="text-right">
    <a href="#" id="yRow"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>&nbsp;New</a>
    <br />
</div>
```

Comment: post full code or better create fiddle link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like this is how you want it

http://jsfiddle.net/xv5rP/

```
<h4 style="display:inline">my text</h4>
<div class="text-right" style="float:right">
  <a href="#" id="yRow"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>&nbsp;New</a>
  <br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `style="display:inline"` to your `<h4>` and `<div>`

```
<h4 style="display:inline">my text</h4>
<div class="text-right" style="display:inline">
    <a href="#" id="yRow"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>&nbsp;New</a>
    <br />
</div>
```

Comment: well this is another way to do it and its great.

Comment: Thanks nicael but the problem is now that the button is coming to left next to the text despite it have text-right,any idea?

Comment: @nicael- ok,before I have table and the text was in the left side of it and the button in the right side of the table ,they was on the table edges ,now the button is coming near to the text,how should I avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

you cant give heading tags, because they take the whole line within itself and anything else after it is showed in the next line. So try some other tag of better use span to style it.
dont use `<p>` either.

Comment: or this could be another way    `<h4 style="display:inline">my text</h4>`